# Flip Everything on Screen After a Fixed Interval has Elapsed - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a timer set up, in place, and working fully.  My problem is that I do not know if it is possible to completely flip everything on screen and keep it in the same position after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

E.G.

I have a tree. After 30 seconds has passed flip the orientation from "landscapeleft" to "landscapeRight" and flip all sprites/timers on screen.

Is it possible?

Should I just change the orientation, check to see if the orientation has changed and if it has, change the sprites rotation?

Also, I would really like to Thank EVERYONE on this site for all of there help and putting up with my "easily answered" questions.

Thank You!

Comment: Scheduling a method call is really easy in cocos2d. On any CC object, call `[self schedule:@methodToBeCalled interval:timeInSeconds]`. But it is entirely unclear what it is that you want to accomplish. What do you mean by "and flip all sprites/timers on screen". When you change the orientation, everything will be upside down. Do you want all sprites to rotate 180 degrees to be upright again? If so, then, why rotate to begin with??

Comment: Yes, I do want everything to be upright again after the orientation has changed and it is just part of my app that I am making.  Also, after everything has flipped and 30 more seconds have passed I want everything to flip again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a scheduling method like nash suggested along with a CCDirector orientation method `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];` or whichever orientation you need.

```
-(void) flipOrientation:(ccTime)delta {

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    if ([director deviceOrientation] == kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
        [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    else 
        [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
}
```

then when you schedule your method

```
[self schedule:@selector(flipOrientation:) interval:30.0];
```

this should do what you are asking for however i **strongly** suggest, as nash said, that you rotate instead of setting the orientation. You can rotate your main layer, or gameScene.. it will be more responsive and you can have control over how it animates. You can do it the same way as above by scheduling but instead of setting device Orientation just rotate your layer.... hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I thought changing the device orientation would be a better idea, but I guess I will rotate the enitre layer instead.  Thanks again kDarker and Nash

Comment: It worked perfectly.  I never even thought about using "self.rotation = 180;"